# rem resize via media queries not working in webkit?

Tags: html, css

I use following code for media queries in my CSS:

```
@media all {html { font-size: 62.5%; }  }/* 62.5%: 1em = 10px */
@media all  and (max-width: 1200px) {   html,body { font-size: 50%; }   }
@media all  and (max-width: 1000px) {   html,body { font-size: 45%; }   }
@media all  and (max-width: 800px) {    html,body { font-size: 40%; }   }
```

but while font sizes > 62.5% resize properly with webkit, sizes <62.5% only resize the texts, but not the widths, heights, paddings etc. of an element.

for instance:

```
.loader {
    width:38rem;
    height:36rem;
    position:relative;
}
```

will only zoom the text in it, not the widths and heights of the element.

This problem only occurs in webkit browsers, not in Firefox: 
[image]

after a lot of research I couldn't find any solution for this problem, any idea?
You can find a live demo here: http://partytube.eu01.aws.af.cm/

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate, oops): [Media queries with rem units in Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201003/media-queries-with-rem-units-in-chrome)

Comment: I have found rem support to be buggy in Chromium (Chrome and Opera). Chromium is webkit-based. I don't know about Safari.

Comment: You probably hit the _scaling_ bug. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=123012 AFAIK it was implemented when iPhone1 came out and has never changed but you can disable it with -webkit-text-size-adjust: none

Answer (score 1):

i think you nedd just change your media queries

```
@media  (max-width: 800px) {    html,body { font-size: 40%; }   }
@media (min-width:801px) and (max-width: 1000px) {   html,body { font-size: 45%; }   }
@media (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 1200px) {   html,body { font-size: 50%; }   }
```