# Media Queries and `rem`s not working in Safari 5.1

Tags: css, safari, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm doing comprehensive browser testing for a responsive web app, and none of my media queries are being computed in Safari 5.1.7. Here are a couple examples:

```
@media all and (min-width:42rem) and (max-width:45rem)

@media all and (min-width:72rem)
```

All of my media queries are laid out like this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not saying this is a duplicate, but this issue affects (or, at least, used to affect) Chrome as well, so it's a bug affecting WebKit and not something unique to Safari. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201003/media-queries-with-rem-units-in-chrome

Comment: Please use px. px is support in all browser

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for pointing that out! That's good to know. Having just done a whole whack of browser testing, I can confirm that the only widely used browser (on our sites at least) that doesn't support the `rem` and media query combo is Safari 5.1.

Comment: @BipinKumarPal Actually, it's much better practice to use `em`s or `rem`s for media queries. You can read more about that here (Jump to #4): http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that in Safari 5.1, though it supports both media queries and `rem`s, it doesn't support them together. Switch the `rem`s in your media queries to `em`s and you'll be good.

This is frustrating though if, like me, you store a lot of your width/breakpoints in SASS or LESS variables for easy reuse, and use them as both breakpoints and widths, the latter where 1rem may not equal 1em. A way to get around this would be adding `font-size:1rem` to the parent element to ensure 1em does equal 1rem, but that's not always possible.